# How do I get selectRowAtIndexPath: to work with willDisplayCell:?

Tags: ios, uitableview

First off I have a custom tableview subclass that uses a uiview subclass with drawRect: to handle the cell's content view. Now since I need a the cell's selected to be a certain color I set the cell's selectedBackgroundView in willDisplayCell:

This works great until I need to scroll to and highlight/select (but not call didSelectCell) upon showing the tableview. When I try to call selectRowAtIndexPath: the tableview scrolls to the cell but the selected color is only shown in the cell where the contentView isn't (by the disclosure arrow).

Now I believe this is because selectRowAtIndexPath: highlights the cell then scrolls to it. And willDisplayCell needs to be invoked before the cell is highlighted. However willDisplayCell is called "only when animating rows as they slide in or out" i.e. after the highlight and before the scroll.

I confirmed this by calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath: then a selectRowAtIndex:animated:scrollPosition: wrapped in a perfomSelector:afterDelay:

How do I fix this without using perfomSelector:afterDelay: ?

Comment: I can recreate the issue with Apple's AdvancedTableViewCells sample code.

Comment: I submitted a Radar: #17701236.